# class name always StudlyCaps or there's exceptions on PSR-1?

Tags: php, psr-1

If the class name a is a abreviation in UPPER case like "CORS", the class name must still be in StudlyCaps like that:

```
class Cors
{
}
```

**Below is the way of my preference, but i would to know if it is an anti-pattern:**

```
class CORS
{
}
```

Comment: a simple naming is neither pattern nor antipattern, though different coding standards have different rules for naming

Comment: I'm talking about PSR-1

Comment: Problem is that if someone will try to define class `Cors` while having already `CORS` - error `Cannot redeclare class Cors` will happen. So please stick to the psr-1

Answer (score 2):

This is [clearly stated](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md):

> Class names MUST be declared in StudlyCaps.
>
> Class constants MUST be declared in all upper case with underscore separators.

There are no exceptions granted in either case. `CORS` is a constant, `Cors` is a class. This is, by definition, an **[absolute requirement](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt)** of the specification. If you want to adhere to a standard, you don't get to pick and choose which parts.

Comment: Maybe you dont understand the question. CORS is not a constant, is an abreviation like SWAT.

Comment: E's not suggesting that your CORS class is a constant, but rather that under the PSR-1 standard the identifier 'CORS' *must be* a constant. The equivalent class name is (and must be) 'Cors'.